# Please assist with modalViewController crash

Tags: iphone, crash, modalviewcontroller, retain, presentmodalviewcontroller

My app  is crashing when I dismiss a ModalViewController via:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This modal view-controller ("MVC") is presented when a user clicks on one of the cells of a UINavigationController ("NavRoot") - here's the code for that:

```
MVC *modalView = [[MVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: modalView animated:YES];
[modalView release];
```

The "modalView" which is loaded contains only 2 objects: a UIWebView object and a "DONE" button, which when clicked-on does the dissmissing via:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Except when I click on "DONE" - the app crashes.

When I run Instruments with NSZombies I do see the retain count reaches -1  but I can't tell what's causing this over-release.

The only thing I found which solves the problem is to either add a "[modalView retain]" statement in "NavRoot" - which is the viewController doing the presenting of modalView:

```
MVC *modalView = [[MVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: modalView animated:YES];
[modalView retain];  //  <<== new 'retain' statement
[modalView release];
```

or just simply never releasing modalView in the first place:

```
MVC *modalView = [[MVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: modalView animated:YES];
// commenting out the 'release':
// [modalView release];
```

Both of these options throw flags when I run "Analyze" ("Potential leak of an object allocated on line 34"...) but they do fix the problem. 
Still, I worry about this causing the app to be rejected by Apple from the App Store.

Any ideas on what may be causing the over-release? Or how I might further try to isolate / identify the problem?

attaching an image of Instruments/Zombies report:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the history from the zombie instrument?

Comment: OK I'll put it up - gotta run right now but will definitely post it as I definitely need to get to the bottom of this!

Comment: What does your MVC dealloc look like? Is MVC acting as the webview's delegate and if so are you cleaning that up in dealloc?

Comment: @Firoze and @ Craig Mellon: well I just looked into all that stuff - and I think it fixed it. The delegate is the "File's Owner" (connected the UIWebView to "file's owner) in Interface Builder, and the I made sure the UIWebView object was also getting released in dealloc - now its not crashing any more. At least not so far. So you definitely pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u using iOS 5? I had the same problem when I switched an app from ios4 to 5.

ParentViewController is now called presentingViewController

What you can do though is in your modal view just call [self dismissModalViewController] and it should dismiss itself.  I'm not 100% about that and can't check as I'm not near my mac, but I recall reading it in the docs,

Comment: I'm using iOS 4.0.2 and "presentingViewController" is iOS 5 only so I can't use that. As far as using plain old [self dismissModalViewCOntroller] - that's how I was doing it from the very beginning - and it worked just fine in terms of the actual physical dismissal of the modalViewController - but the app was crashing. I researched and found the suggestion to use "[self.ParentViewController dismissModalViewController]" - which also worked, but was also causing crashes.  So the app crashes no matter what variation of "self" I use. But its not about that. Its about a retain/release issue (cont.)

Comment: It seems I am releasing  - or trying to talk to - a viewController which is no longer there. Its already been released somehow. But I can't figure out what released it. Any ideas?

Comment: I once had a problem with web requests, because they were async, if I set a webrequest off, and then dismissed my modal view controller, the webrequest was trying to call a method in my viewcontroller which had now being release.  My problem was that I wasn't clearing my delegate on the web request.  So I would check your dealloc method in the modal view controller and make sure your are setting your delegates to nil on the webview, and cancel any requests on the webview.  I've not used the webview before so not sure what you need to check, but thats the first place I would look.

Comment: @Firoze and @ Craig Mellon: well I just looked into all that stuff - and I think it fixed it. The delegate is the "File's Owner" (connected the UIWebView to "file's owner) in Interface Builder, and the I made sure the UIWebView object was also getting released in dealloc - now its not crashing any more. At least not so far. So you definitely pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If you do

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: modalView animated:YES];`

Then you should dismiss it like

`[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Rather than

`[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Where are you trying to dismiss the view from? The actual modalView or the parentView? It seems to me that you are trying to dismiss a modal view that has already been dismissed and subsequently released.

Comment: I am dismissing the modalView from within itself. There's a "DONE" button inside the modalView that when clicked on, calls the "[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];" statement.   I just tried switching it to "[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];" - and now it doesn't do anything. It doesn't release the modalView at all, it just sits there...

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss a `modalViewController` I simply just do: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Answer (score 0):

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` does not work on iOS 5.

I have built a category that add `presentingViewController` on iOS 4. (It disables itself on iOS 5.)

Just include 2 files, and it works seamlessly.

Please see [backward-modal](http://github.com/tanin47/backward-modal.git).

I hope this benefits you as much as it does to me; It makes your code more clean!